# Trying to perform divison using MySQL subqueries but getting syntax error

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1064, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to get the value from MySQL subqueries but I am getting 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1'

The code is:

```
UPDATE national_avg_tariff SET Value= (CASE WHEN ((SELECT * FROM((SELECT Value 
                                                    / ((Select Sum_CPP_MlnRs from ppp_fy2020_2030_annex4.FY_CPP_exclKE_MlnRs where FiscalYear=2020) + (Select UoSC_MoF_exclKE_MlnRs from ppp_fy2020_2030_annex4.FY_UoSC_MoF_exclKE_MlnRs where FiscalYear=2020))/ (SELECT Sum(Sum_of_AvgMW) FROM ppp_fy2020_2030_annex4.AVG_OF_FY_MAX_DEMAND where FiscalYear=2020 GROUP BY FiscalYear)FROM tariff_true_cost.national_avg_tariff WHERE Sector='Residential' AND Category='Up to 50 Units' AND Parameter= 'Fixed Charge(Rs/kW/M)' AND FiscalYear=2020)temptbl8))>0)
                                                    THEN 
                                                    (SELECT * FROM((SELECT Value 
                                                    / ((Select Sum_CPP_MlnRs from ppp_fy2020_2030_annex4.FY_CPP_exclKE_MlnRs where FiscalYear=2020) + (Select UoSC_MoF_exclKE_MlnRs from ppp_fy2020_2030_annex4.FY_UoSC_MoF_exclKE_MlnRs where FiscalYear=2020))/ (SELECT Sum(Sum_of_AvgMW) FROM ppp_fy2020_2030_annex4.AVG_OF_FY_MAX_DEMAND where FiscalYear=2020 GROUP BY FiscalYear)FROM tariff_true_cost.national_avg_tariff WHERE Sector='Residential' AND Category='Up to 50 Units' AND Parameter= 'Fixed Charge(Rs/kW/M)' AND FiscalYear=2020)temptbl8))
                                                    ELSE NULL END) where FiscalYear=2020 AND Parameter='Fixed Charge(%)';
```

The code doesn't show any red underline or pre-execution error something, the error only appears once I execute it.

Any help in rectifying syntax error of this piece of code would be appreciable.  Thanks

Comment: This will be difficult to answer because there is not enough information for people to run the query themselves, to test any fixes. I did not try to parse this thing myself, but I get the feeling it would be a lot simpler with window functions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: To troubleshoot this kind of thing, first write a SELECT statement, get it working, and inspect the results. Format the SELECT so each significant hunk of code is on its own line, to make the error message's line number more useful. Start with the innermost subqueries and work your way out.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. That's exactly what I did when I first encountered this error. I ran every inner subquery and got it working i.e. it gave a single value. but as soon as I try to perform: a/((b+c)/d), I get that error. a,b,c and d being separate subqueries.